# Blockquote CSS on same line

Tags: css, quotes

This is probably really simple but I am using the code provided here

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ModernBlockQuoteStyles

And I can't figure out how to get two or three quote boxes on the same line
So if we create another quote, a 2nd one, it would appear on the same line as the 1st, without skipping to the next line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no code it is hard to guess what you mean but try

```
blockquote{
display:inline-block;
}
```

You should reference [MDN on display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and consider using [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)